# I had a problem while trying to genrate automatically the table in the database in spring boot using JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

can anyone help me please to fix this proble, iwant to generate automaticallly with jpa my table in sql , i can't see any problem in my work .. i did many projects but it is always the same proble. I dont receive any error but the table also doesnt want to create in my database

So this is my application.properties :

````
server.port=8285
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
### JPA / HIBERNATE ###
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect  ```
````

My Entity:

```
package com.entite;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table( name = "T_EMPLOYEE")
public class Product implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name="EMPL_ID")
private long id;
   @Column(name="EMPLi_name")
private String name;
   private String role;
   public long getId() {
       return id;
   }
   public void setId(long id) {
       this.id = id;
   }
   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }
   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }
   public String getRole() {
       return role;
   }
   public void setRole(String role) {
       this.role = role;
   }
   public Product(String name, String role) {

       this.name = name;
       this.role = role;
   }
   public Product() {}
   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return "User [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", role=" + role + "]";
   }
   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
       final int prime = 31;
       int result = 1;
       result = prime * result + (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
       result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
       result = prime * result + ((role == null) ? 0 : role.hashCode());
       return result;
   }
   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       if (this == obj)
           return true;
       if (obj == null)
           return false;
       if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
           return false;
       Product other = (Product) obj;
       if (id != other.id)
           return false;
       if (name == null) {
           if (other.name != null)
               return false;
       } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
           return false;
       if (role == null) {
           if (other.role != null)
               return false;
       } else if (!role.equals(other.role))
           return false;
       return true;
   }
   
   
}
```

JPARepository

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.entite.Product;
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long>{

}
```

###This is what it says ###

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
\\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
 '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
=========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
:: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.2)

2021-01-17 15:34:45 - INFO  - com.salon.Application - Starting Application using Java 1.8.0_271 on LAPTOP-7C6GGTA9 with PID 22672 (C:\Users\zizoe\eclipse-workspace\SpringBoot\target\classes started by zizoe in C:\Users\zizoe\eclipse-workspace\SpringBoot)
2021-01-17 15:34:45 - INFO  - com.salon.Application - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-01-17 15:34:46 - INFO  - o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-01-17 15:34:46 - INFO  - o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 6 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-01-17 15:34:47 - INFO  - o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8285 (http)
2021-01-17 15:34:47 - INFO  - o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-01-17 15:34:47 - INFO  - o.a.catalina.core.StandardEngine - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.41]
2021-01-17 15:34:47 - INFO  - o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-01-17 15:34:47 - INFO  - o.s.b.w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1301 ms
2021-01-17 15:34:47 - INFO  - o.h.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-01-17 15:34:47 - INFO  - org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.27.Final
2021-01-17 15:34:47 - INFO  - o.h.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-01-17 15:34:47 - INFO  - com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-01-17 15:34:48 - INFO  - com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-01-17 15:34:48 - INFO  - org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2021-01-17 15:34:48 - INFO  - o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator - HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-01-17 15:34:48 - INFO  - o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-01-17 15:34:48 - WARN  - o.s.b.a.o.j.JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration - spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-01-17 15:34:48 - INFO  - o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-01-17 15:34:48 - INFO  - o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat started on port(s): 8285 (http) with context path ''
2021-01-17 15:34:48 - INFO  - com.salon.Application - Started Application in 3.431 seconds (JVM running for 4.228)
```

**I do appreciate if you guys helps :(**

Comment: can you add a constructor with all the attributes not just name and role , and change id from long to Long , and tell me if the problem persists ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

With

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

Comment: it says "unknow property"

Answer (score 0):

Can you try including below properties also?

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

Comment: i try it but it wasn't the problem... But thank god i solve it thank u :)

Answer (score 0):

Can u try adding this to Main Class?

```
@EntityScan("org.example.base.entities")
```

where **org.example.base.entities** is the package name for entities, in your case it can be anything